# Кто должен переводить контент, заказчик или верстальщик?

Tags: вёрстка

Делаю мультиязычнай сайт там 3 языка, хотел спросить у более опытных, контент который предоставит мне клиент для размещения на сайте клиент должен перевести сам и послать мне готовый текст? Или переводом контента тоже верстальщики должны заниматься?

Comment: Конечно клиент должен предоставить переводы как и оригинальный язык

Answer (score 4):

Клиент должен все предоставить. Задача верстальщика только правильно сверстать, руководствуясь ТЗ.

Comment: Ага ну да ну да :) заказчики разные бывают. Все зависит от того как вы договорились на этапе начала разработки. А если в начале не договорились то нужно уже договариваться на этапе возникновения задачи по локализации

Comment: @totorro верно, но полагать, что верстальщик еще и опытный переводчик глупо)) да еще и на 2 языка